# KRL gem and msvcrt-ruby*.dll

Tags: ruby, rubygems, krl

When I run the KRL command line tool from the KRL gem on Windows it complains that I don't have the right msvcrt-ruby dll. When I'm set up to run Ruby 187 it complains that it can't find the ruby191 dll. When I'm set up for Ruby 191 it complains about the missing Ruby 187 dll. When I put both .dll files in the path it fails with an unexpected termination. It still works with just one DLL in the path, I just have to dismiss the annoying dialog every time I run the KRL tool.

The gem was working fine under Ruby 187, then I did 'gem update' and it started failing.

Is my Ruby installation misconfigured or is it a problem with the KRL gem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [krl](https://rubygems.org/gems/krl) gem depends on [kynetx_am_api](https://rubygems.org/gems/kynetx_am_api) gem, which at the same time depends on JSON gem.

JSON binaries for Windows are broken between versions of Ruby. This has been reported to the gem author but still the binaries are available.

Please read [this post](http://carol-nichols.com/2011/02/the-json-gem-strikes-again-heroku-on-windows/) for instructions. You will need DevKit installed and configured and proceed to the command line to remove the existing JSON gem and replace with the compiled one.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I still had the JSON gem 1.4.6 installed, removing 1.5.1 stopped the madness.

Comment: This is a great response. The KRL gem has only been tested on 1.8.7 on Windows with the setup instructions that are out on http://github.com/kynetx/krl  We've also not tested this lately with newer versions of the gem. Please submit an issue on github and we'll follow up.